# detect mobile operator by number

Tags: mobile-phones

Where can i find database, phone numbers masks for mobile operators, or just web site, where i can detect mobile operator by phone number?

Comment: not programming related.

Comment: Which country are we talking about?

Comment: In the UK, don't know how it works elsewhere: The STD code may initially indicate the carrier, but with number portability, this becomes volatile as users move their number between carriers. Also, having said database for a given identified person would surely be privacy issue?

Comment: Number portability exists in Spain as well.

Comment: @Program.X: A user's IP address can be traced to an ISP, I see no difference between that and tracing a phone number to a mobile operator.

Comment: skaffman: Yes, you can lookup an IP because there's a global database maintained by IANA etc. There is no such global database for mobile phones numbers. Plus, as Program.X mentioned, even if you use the STD code, there's the issue of number portability.

Comment: in IANA database not actual data to detect mobile operator

Answer (score 3):

I know this out of date, but you would need to do something called a HLR lookup via a sms gateway, InfoBip for example.

Answer (score 1):

In the UK, you cannot do this. Numbers can be ported from operator to operator, it's all very fluid. Each operator will know how to route these numbers between themselves, but they don't expose that routing to outside parties.

Answer (score 0):

Not in Australia - mobile numbers might be handed to operators in blocks, but they belong to the user and can be ported to any carrier the user chooses to use.

Of course, there are still ways to look up an individual number and find out which carrier it's on - there have to be, in order for the call to be routed to the appropriate carrier. You're not going to get access to that without investing a significant amount of money to set up a telco though.

All of this is almost certainly irrelevant to you as you didn't say you were specifically interested in australia; but then again, you didn't say you weren't interested in Australia either.

Answer (score 0):

I found such a service which seems to provide an API for lookup of the operator in many countries around the world: http://numberportabilitylookup.com/